# Youtube Embedded Video

Tags: youtube, embed

I have a youtube video embedded on a web page. Some of the users in my office do not have access to youtube and when they open this page, Access Denied page on my server shows up. which is pretty ok.

Now what i want to do is to see if the video player has not been loaded, that means the specific user does not have access to youtube. How can i determine this from my website (which is in php) and show some other image in place of youtube player.